# Can we say that this system has a memory?

Tags: signal, signal-processing, system

This unit step response has a memory because of (n+1) but can we say that whole system is not memoryless? If we can, why?

[image]

Comment: You're wanting the site to be a free homework-answering and personal tutorial service. Here, people will help you take the next step - if your questions show you've done as much as you possibly could. Which this doesn't, I'm afraid. Please edit your question and greatly improve it. Show your own work and your own findings in considerable detail. The better the quality of your questions, the better the quality of the answers you will attract.

Comment: @TonyM how can I show that I found that this equation has a memory? I already wrote that it has a memory because of (n+1) and I couldn't make what I asked so what can I show you? The question is in the picture, what didn't you understand? I don't really understan, why everyone would like to see more complicated and long questions in this site.

Comment: I have explained why very clearly. Please look at other well-voted questions for examples of what's expected.

Comment: `why everyone would like to see more complicated and long questions` ... not questions ... more detailed solution attempts ... your post does not contain any information about your gap in knowledge, information that could be used to guide you

Comment: @jsotola So I can't ask any question if it can't be used to guide .

Comment: @Mert No, you are misreading what he is saying. He is saying tell us what you do know.

Answer (score 4):

The output depends on **only** the current input:

$$
s(n)=(n+1)\cdot u(n)
$$

For a system to have memory, the output should depend on the previous and/or the future inputs i.e. \$u(n-1)\$ and/or \$u(n+1)\$. The term \$(n+1)\$ does not bring memory to the system. Don't mix this with \$u(n+1)\$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Our lecturer said that y(n)=n*x(n) has a memory because we need to track n (she sai time). And my question was if unit step response of a system has a memory , then does whole system have a memory. I understood from your answer: yes, it does

Comment: @Mert `then does whole system have a memory. I understood from your answer: yes, it does` nope, you don't understand. Read carefully.

Answer (score 0):

Because transfer function with dependent variable n (usually time) also includes n in the response, it must have memory and as well as store energy with the increase in n.  (+1 is irrelevant to the question)

Comment: Discrete-time systems have 3 time-related property: Causalty, Memory and Time-invariance. For a memory-less system the output must depend on **only** to the current input i.e. \$u(n)\$ or \$x(n)\$. So the system does not have memory. \$(n+1)\$ does not bring memory.

Comment: n is  an integrator which has memory. Using the non-inverting input only adds +1

Comment: But n is the input to the system, no?

Comment: The input is u(n) and the output is s(n) which integrates n ( memory)

Comment: @RohatKılıç  I don't understand your logic. sorry I must need coffee